# Laravel 4 Paginantor::make, returning same data on every page

Tags: methods, laravel-4, pagination

I have a set of documents, which I have stored in an array `$resultset`. I want to apply laravel Paginator::make method on it.

```
In Controller: 
    $total_resultset = count($resultset);
    $perPage = 10;
    $currentPage = Input::get('pageno',1);
    $offSet = ($currentPage * $perPage) - $perPage;
    $pagedData = array_slice($resultset, $offSet,$perPage, true);
    $resultset = Paginator::make($pagedData, $total_resultset, $perPage);

 and in view:

   @foreach($resultset as $r)
    $r->title
    @endforeach
    {{ $resultset->links() }}
```

The problem is, when I use `$PagedData` in `Paginator::make` it returns 10 docs per page. But all of the pages have same set of documents, rather than different docs, the page=2 does not show new set of docs. And when I use `$resultset` in `Paginator::make` it returns me all of the documents rather than only 10.

I can't use Eloquent or DB query as the `$resultset` has docs, based on different queries. I'm confused where I'm wrong.

P.S I've been trying to solve the issue since last two days, but didn't get successful. Please help me out, any kind of help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
$total_resultset = count($resultset);
$perPage = 10;
$currentPage = Input::get('pageno',0); //if you use default 1 you will skip 10 results
$offSet = ($currentPage * $perPage);// Ex: (1*10)= 10 - 10 = 0 you are not moving
$pagedData = array_slice($resultset, $offSet,$perPage, false);//maybe you are using Eloquent? you can use take() and skip() if is the case;  and you was preserving the array keys in slice so never move really
$resultset = Paginator::make($pagedData, $total_resultset, $perPage);
```

hope helps :)

Comment: thanks for your reply, actually the problem was in `Input::get('pageno',1)` it should be `Input::get('page',1), as the pageno isn't anything and the `$currnetPage` is always 1, that's why it was showing same data on every page. But I really appreaciate it, that you replied. Thanks again :)